# How do I make "9/10" a "4.5/5" on an android RatingBar?

Tags: android, ratingbar

The [Rating bar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#attr_android:isIndicator) in Android has the attributes [numStars](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#attr_android:numStars) to represent the total number of stars displayed, and the attribute [stepSize](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#attr_android:stepSize) to represent the granularity of scale.

However, I want to have a rating scale of 10 mapped to a RatingBar of 5 stars, so that a 9/10 is shown on the scale as 4.5/5 stars. Is this possible for the android Rating Bar?

Comment: you want five stars.... with a rating of 0-10? that doesnt make sense to me.

Comment: @DroiDev I have data coming in from a JSON that returns a float from 0 - 10.  However, I have project specs that require a 5 star scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide the **number** by two in order to end up with your value over 5:

In your case it is 9, so it's **9/2 = 4.5**.

Then, pass that value to your ratingBar:

```
// Retrieved Json Object. float might be redundant 
//if getNumber is already of type float
float ratingValue = (float) object.getNumber()/2;

// This is used to set the rating value
myRatingBar.setRating(ratingValue); 

// This is used to show your stars
myRatingBar.setStepSize(ratingValue);
```